# Random image after click onclass react-native

Tags: image, react-native, random

my code is not working and my photo is not displayed.
I try different options but I don’t get it.
Maybe you know what this could be too problematic?

```html
const images= [
  image2 = './assets/images/geltonas_trikampis.png',
  image3 = './assets/images/zalias_trikampis.png',
  image4 = './assets/images/juodas_trikampis.png',
  image6 = './assets/images/raudonas_trikampis.png',
  ];

  changeImage = () => {
    console.log('Working');
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    this.setState({
      currenturiImageIndex: randomNumber,
    });
  }
  
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.changeImage()}>
      <Image
    source={this.state.currenturiImageIndex}
    style={styles.logoStyle}
  /></TouchableOpacity>
```

I get the result on the console, but I don't show the photo and I don't know what else might be after the click.

I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You are providing an integer value to source prop.

Please change below

```
source={this.state.currenturiImageIndex}
```

to

```
source={images[this.state.currenturiImageIndex]}
```

Hope. this works!!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to do what Siddharth Mishra suggests here and change your code to `source={images[this.state.currentuirImageIndex]}`.

The other thing you need to check, if that is not the only issue, is that you are giving your image a `height` and `width`. You can either set them as `props`, or set them in your `style`, but if you don't give them a height and width then they will default to 0.

Comment: I don't see a picture, although I wrote the code well:

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.changeImage()}>
      <Image
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={styles.logotipas}
      source={images[this.state.currenturiImageIndex]}
  /></TouchableOpacity>`
And my style is 100% working.
`const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  logotipas: {
    width: 100,
    height: 200
  }`

I have no errors, but image is not working.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, try adding the width and height as props instead of styles.